# How to prevent multiple injection of content script when disabling/re-enabling safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, safari-content-script

If Safari, I end up with multiple copies of the content script being injected if I disable and then re-enable the extension in the same session.

After page refresh, things return to normal. Chrome has a concept of an "invalidated extension context" that Safari seems to lack.

The content script(script.js) is registered by adding it in Safari extension app in xcode under key *SFSafariContentScript*. According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/injecting_a_script_into_a_webpage?language=objc, content script is always injected when extension is loaded. Is there a work around to prevent it from being injected again if it is already injected the first time?

I did quite some research online but can't find a solution. Any suggestion are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's a default behaviour.
if web-page has child frames, script will be injected to all the frames.

But you can prevent multiple calls by checking if its main-frame.

```
        //sample function
        function foo() 
        {
           if (window.top === window)  //main-frame only
           { 
            //place code here.
           }
        }
```